# how to send ussd using node-smpp?

Tags: javascript, smpp, ussd

send submit_sm

```
session.submit_sm({
                source_addr_ton: 0x05,
                source_addr_npi: 0x01,
                source_addr: 'myphone',
                dest_addr_ton: 0x01,
                dest_addr_npi: 0x01,
                destination_addr: '*100#',
        }, (pdu) => {
                    console.log('session.submit_sm pdu=');
                    console.log(pdu);
                }
            });
```

getting status 69
submit_sm failed
how to send ussd to number: *100# ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - [tour]. Please [edit] your question and provide the code you're using and a more detailed description of both the problem and the errors you might have. See [ask].